# Would the dimensions of hyperspace be the 4th, 5th, and 6th spatial dimensions?

Tags: science-based, physics, spacetime-dimensions

The dimensions of our world are X, Y, and Z; while the dimensions of hyperspace are X’, Y’, and Z’. So, the extra dimensional theories all state that the extra dimensions are inside of the observable 3. Does that mean that the 3d’ dimensions are “higher” dimensions that we can’t normally perceive?

Bending of current knowledge is fine.

Comment: This question is entirely dependent upon how you define your terms. Since none of your terms are defined this question is unanswerable. Alternatively since none of the terms are defined you can answer this question however you want. Either way it's not an appropriate question for this site.

Comment: If you want to have this science-based, work it out properly. I would vote for reopen.. What "extra dimensional theories" state that the extra dimensions are inside of the observable 3 ? the concept of hyperspace relies on the idea you can travel through shortcut dimensions, that is reach XYZ places faster than light, like a worm hole would allow. In order to do that, the extra dimensions should be independent, not inside the other 3. Can you explain  what you mean by "inside" please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept of extra dimensions in real-world physics is always associated with string theory. In string theory, the extra dimensions are all cylindrical, such that travel in that direction will always get you back to the starting point after a certain distance. That distance would have to be REEEEEALLY small, otherwise we'd have noticed them before now. Like smaller than a neutron kind of small.

If you're talking about hyperspace, then you're talking about moving out of the current volume (or brane) and into a volume where the points corresponding to ours aren't as far apart. As an example, imagine a smaller planet inside of the earth. If you tunnel into the earth until you reach that other planet, then move around on that planet, then tunnel back, the total distance traveled COULD be less than if you moved around on the surface. That's how hyperspace would work.

In science fiction, the transition to hyperspace is usually portrayed as a nearly instantaneous jump. So you jump to a sphere the size of a desktop globe [image], move around on the globe, then jump back to the corresponding place on the full-sized planet.

In that model, every point on the globe directly corresponds to a point on the planet. The latitude, longitude, and maybe even altitude are translatable to equivalents between the two spheres.

If you want to go one step further, you could specify a Q dimension that tells you how deep into this model you go, so theoretically you could rabbit-hole yourself, taking the shortest (Q, X, Y, Z) path through the hypersphere of the universe.

Comment: So, to be clear: no, you don't need 3 more dimensions of hyperspace. 1 additional dimension is sufficient.